# Wpf использование джостика

Tags: c#, wpf, разработка-игр, usb

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в WPF можно работать с джостиком подключённым через USB?(Подскажите, хотя бы куда смотреть, а то я пока вообще незнаю, что делать)

Comment: А причём тут WPF? WPF — это UI-фреймворк, а с джойстиком работайте через его API.

Comment: ок. так как всётаки можно добраться до его API?

Comment: Ну, скорее всего API есть на сайте производителя. А может, джойстик считается стандартным устройством, и вы можете достучаться к нему через WinAPI, я не знаю точно. Но в любом случае WPF вряд ли вам поможет в работе с джойстиком.